# How to access remote database's tables in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am accessing the remote database in my Django project as follows:

> settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
},
'remote_db' : {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'db_name',
    'USER': 'db_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'db_password',
    'HOST': '192.*.*.*',
    'PORT': '1433',

}
```

}

For accessing default database table's data, I use the following syntax:

```
from app_name.models import mymodel

mymodel.objects.all()
```

My remote database has tables like reports, emplayee_data, etc that are already there and my project has no models defined for these tables.
I need to access these tables and I am unsure how to perform this action.

```
remote_db.reports.all()
```

All in all, my main objective is to copy the data from **remote_db** to **default** database.

> Note:
> remote_db gets new data everyday.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to also define models for reports and employee_data in this project.

And then you can use them like the following:

```
reports.objects.using('remote_db').all()
```

Comment: I need to copy data from remote_db to the default database.

Comment: You can create another app and define the model classes in your project. But you won't make migrations and migrate for that app. So the real tables won't be generated in the `default` database.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that there are no models defined for the tables. I think it will be a good option to make a script to fetch data from **remote_db** and add it to **default**. You will have to use raw SQL to do that if you don't create models for those tables. Another option would be getting the **remote_db** dump and importing it to the **default** database.

Comment: for the second option, is it feasible to dump data, as the remote_db gets new data everyday.

Comment: You can make a cron job to do the data update which can run every day. If you do that you will have to handle old data and new data properly to mitigate data redundancy problems.